# Is there a master list of all company CIK numbers that I can add to a program?

Tags: python

I am looking to download a master list that is current with all company CIK numbers to add to my program. Please let me know if there are any available.

Answer (score 0):

Name, Ticker and CIK are here but it's slow to load: https://www.sec.gov/files/company_tickers.json
Here's the format, each item on a separate line:
cik_str: 320193
ticker: "AAPL"
title:  "Apple Inc."
According to the bar across the top of the list, it can be copied.
There's also a simpler list that may not be completely current at: https://www.sec.gov/include/ticker.txt